# Why am I getting DoesNotExist for the parent model in save_related

Tags: django, django-admin, celery

I am firing a celery task in `save_related` that takes the parent object id and does a get query to obtain the instance for use.

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    ...
    # Some stuff happens earlier here that don't access the db
    args = (var1, var2, var3, form.instance.id)
    logger.debug(f"Sending stuff to celery for bulk update")
    jobs = group(
    bulk_update_stuff_in_admin.s(ids_chunk, *args) for ids_chunk in chunks(ids, 128)
    )
    jobs()
    super().save_related(request, form, formsets, change)


@celery_app.task
def bulk_update_stuff_in_admin(var1, var2, var3, parent_id):
    parent = ParentModel.objects.get(id=parent_id)
    ...
```

Problem is some of the get queries are failing with `DoesNotExist`. This doesn't make sense to me because the Django docs clearly state that ["Note that at this point the parent object and its form have already been saved."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related). Also why are others not failing?

I am about to experiment with what happens when I call `super().save_related(...)` before the celery task but I don't think that should be an issue because of the note above.

Django==4.2.3